# What is an easy way to add n number of spaces to a string?

Tags: c#

I would like to add n number of spaces to a string in C#.

I know this can be achieved with a for loop, but I was wondering if there was a nice one liner for it?

```
String newStr = "";
for(int i = numSpaces; i > 0; i--)
    newStr += " ";
```

Comment: [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For N number of spaces, use this String constructor:

`new string(' ', N)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to add *n* spaces, not add spaces until the total length is *n*, you can use [this String constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
newstr += new String(' ', numSpaces);
```